# SQL Distinct / GroupBy

Tags: sql, postgresql, objection.js

Ok, I’m stuck on an SQL query and tried long enough that it’s time to ask for help :) I'm using Objection.js – but that's not super relevant as I really just can't figure out how to structure the SQL.

I have the following example data set:

**Items**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 |
| 2 | Test 2 |
| 3 | Test 3 |

**Listings**

| id | item_id | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 1654640000 |
| 2 | 1 | 60 | 1654640001 |
| 3 | 1 | 80 | 1654640002 |
| 4 | 2 | 90 | 1654640003 |
| 5 | 2 | 90 | 1654640004 |
| 6 | 3 | 50 | 1654640005 |

**What I’m trying to do:**

- Return the lowest priced listing for each item
- If all listings for an item have the same price, I want to return the newest of the two items
- Overall, I want to return the resulting items by price

**I’m trying to write a query that returns the data:**

| id | item_id | name | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | Test 3 | 50 | 1654640005 |
| 2 | 1 | Test 1 | 60 | 1654640001 |
| 5 | 2 | Test 2 | 90 | 1654640004 |

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated! I'm also starting fresh, so I can add new columns to the data if that would help at all :)

---

An example of where my query is right now:

```
select * from "listings" inner join (select "item_id", MIN(price) as "min_price" from "listings" group by "item_id") as "grouped_listings" on "listings"."item_id" = "grouped_listings"."item_id" and "listings"."price" = "grouped_listings"."min_price" where "listings"."sold_at" is null and "listings"."expires_at" > ? order by CAST(price AS DECIMAL) ASC limit ?;
```

This gets me listings – but if two listings have the same price, it returns multiple listings with the same item_id – not ideal.

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? It can be a good starter for a code that maybe needs just a quick fix. @MikeFogg

Comment: Hey @lemon! It's tough because the actual example is complicated, but let me see if I can simplify it to fit this example :)

Comment: Edited with an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the postgresql tag, this should work:

```sql
with listings_numbered as (
  select *, row_number() over (
    partition by item_id
    order by price asc, created_at desc
  ) as rownum
  from listings
)
select l.id, l.item_id, i.name, l.price, l.created_at
from listings_numbered l
join items i on l.item_id=i.id
where l.rownum=1
order by price asc;
```

This is a bit of an advanced query, using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html) and a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html), but we can break it down.

`with listings_numbered as (...) select` simply means to run the query inside of the `...`, and then we can refer to the results of that query as `listings_numbered` inside of the select, as though it was a table.

We're selecting all of the columns in `listings`, plus one more:
`row_number() over (partition by item_id order by price asc, created_at desc)`. `partition by item_id` means that we would like the row number to reset for each new `item_id`, and the `order by` specifies the ordering that the rows should get within each partition before we number them: first increasing by price, then decreasing by creation time to break ties.

The result of the CTE `listings_numbered` looks like:

| id | item_id | price | created_at | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 60 | 1654640001 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 80 | 1654640002 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 1654640000 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 90 | 1654640004 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 90 | 1654640003 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 50 | 1654640005 | 1 |

If you look at only the rows where `rownum` (the last column) is 1, then you can see that it's exactly the set of listings that you're interested in.

The outer query then selects from this this dataset, joins on `items` to get the name, filters to only the listings where `rownum` is 1, and sorts by price, to get the final result:

| id | item_id | name | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | Test 3 | 50 | 1654640005 |
| 2 | 1 | Test 1 | 60 | 1654640001 |
| 5 | 2 | Test 2 | 90 | 1654640004 |

Comment: Window functions are amazing – and I am in shock at how helpful this is. This worked perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation functions, as the `MIN` function you employed in your query, is a viable option, yet if you want to have an efficient query for your problem, [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) can be your best friends. This class of functions allow to compute values over "windows" (partitions) of your table given some specified columns.

For the solution to this problem I'm going to compute two values using the window functions:

- the minimum value for "*listings.price*", by partitioning on "*listings.item_id*",
- the maximum value for "*created_at*", by partitioning on "*listings.item_id*" and *listings.price*

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(price)      OVER(PARTITION BY item_id)        AS min_price,
       MAX(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id, price) AS max_created_at
FROM listings
```

Once you have all records of listings associated to the corresponding minimum price and latest date, it's necessary for you to select the records whose

- *price* equals the minimum *price*
- *created_at* equals the most recent *created_at*

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           MIN(price)      OVER(PARTITION BY item_id)        AS min_price,
           MAX(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id, price) AS max_created_at
    FROM listings
)
SELECT id, 
       item_id, 
       price, 
       created_at
FROM cte
WHERE price = min_price
  AND created_at = max_created_at
```

If you need to order by price, it's sufficient to add a `ORDER BY price` clause.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnj9ZGWTf9z9xRNuLrZKEA/1).

Comment: Also a great answer! I found the window function to be such a good way of doing it, thanks a ton for taking the time!